# Escaping html for meta description

Tags: php, escaping

I am using this code to add to my posts a meta description from a custom field.

```
$des = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'fl_description', true);
  if( ! empty( $des )  ){
    $meta_des = esc_html($des);
    echo '<meta name="description" content="' . $meta_des . '" />';
```

However, I need to completely escape all html tags and shortcodes. i.e the input

```
<p><span class="x-dropcap">D</span>esigned by interior mastermind Chams it is one of the only top <strong>members</strong> clubs where partying and dining co-exist under one roof. </p>
```

needs to become:

```
Designed by interior mastermind Chams it is one of the only top members clubs where partying and dining co-exist under one roof.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To strip HTML tags and shortcodes, use a combination of PHP's strip_tags ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php ) and WordPress's strip_shortcodes ( https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/strip_shortcodes )

```
$meta_des = strip_shortcodes( strip_tag( $des ) );
```

Comment: strip tag works !